# hive get percentages of count column not working

Tags: sql, hive, cloudera

i have the following query in hive to get the counts per each of those columns (cluster, country and airline) as a percentage. But my percentage column contains only 0's.. why/what am i doing wrong below?

```
 select 
    
        count(*)/ t.cnt * 100 AS percentage,
        cluster,
        country,
        airline 
        from 

        table1
 CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM table1 ) t
 GROUP
    BY cluster,
        country,
        airline
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should use window functions.

Second, beware of integer division.

I would phrase this as:

```
select count(*) * 100.0 / sum(count(*)) over ()  AS percentage,
       cluster, country, airline 
from table1
group by cluster, country, airline;
```